# How to call mongoose method in the select method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, getter

I have a mongoose model that represents a player and want to be able to fetch the player and when selecting the player, want to call `isReady` like a getter.

The model looks like so:

```
const PlayerSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  famousPerson: { type: String }
})

PlayerSchema.methods.isReady = function (cb) {
  return Boolean(this.famousPerson)
}
```

And I want to be able to call it like so:

```
const player = await PlayerModel
      .findOne({_id: playerId})
      .select(["_id", "username", "isReady"])
```

Am I able to set the method on the class as a getter?

Comment: Why don't you just keep the famousPerson field as boolean so that you don't need such method?

Comment: Because it needs to be a string. It's a value that gets set by user input

Comment: What is RoomModel in the query? Did you mean PlayerModel?

Comment: Woops, yes I did. Have updated

Comment: Is username a field in the schema?

Comment: username is a field in the user schema

Comment: You need to populate the user to get the username, but there is no populate code in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongoose virtuals for this, but to work as expected you need to configure your schema so that it can return virtuals, because by default virtuals will not be included.

```js
const PlayerSchema = new Schema(
  {
    famousPerson: { type: String },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

PlayerSchema.virtual("isReady").get(function () {
  return Boolean(this.famousPerson);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Follow This Code**

```
const player = await PlayerModel
      .findOne({_id: playerId})
      .select(" +_id +username +isReady)
```

Comment: You're missing the part where `isReady` is defined in the model